# Perl replace every occurrence differently

Tags: regex, perl

In a perl script, I need to replace several strings. At the moment, I use:

```
$fasta =~ s/\>[^_]+_([^\/]+)[^\n]+/\>$1/g;
```

The aim is to format in a FASTA file every sequence name. It works well in my case so I don't need to touch this part. However, it happens that a sequence name appears several times in the file. I must not have at the end twice - or more - the same sequence name. I thus need to have for instance:

```
seqName1
seqName2
etc.
```

(instead of seqName, seqName, etc.)

Is this possible to somehow process differently every occurrence automatically? I don't know how many sequence there are, if there are similar names, etc. An idea would be to concatenate a random string at every occurrence for instance, hence my question.

Many thanks.

---

John perfectly solved it and chepner helped with the smart idea to avoid conflicts, here is the final result:

```
$fasta =~ s/\>[^_]+_([^\/]+)[^\n]+/
    sub {
        return '>'.$1.$i++;
    }->();
/eg;
```

Many many thanks.

Comment: Check whether Perl allow you to pass in a function to handle the replacement.

Comment: I vainly tried to add a `rand(999)` in the regex. The text in the regex is considered as text, not code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually trying to do something like this the other day, here's what I came up with

```
$fasta =~ s/\>[^_]+_([^\/]+)[^\n]+/

    sub {

        # return random string

    }->();

/eg;
```

the `\e` modifier interprets the substitution as code, not text. I use an anonymous code ref so that I can return at any point.

Comment: I didn't know that one, many thanks. I still need to conserve the sequence name (`$1`). Any idea on how to still display it? For now I can only replace with a full random string instead of a partial one.

Comment: you can still use the `$1` in the subroutine

Comment: Instead of a random string (it *might* produce a collision), just return an ever-increasing number: `sub { $i++ }` You could also keep a hash that maps each `$1` to its own sequence.

Comment: Thanks for it, I thought about conflicts but did not care a lot (in my case). The solution to solve it is simple thus I implemented it as well.